# how to display first item from the model class using services and controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-migrations

I have model Class Doctor.This class is having one WebApi controller.I have Created 3 scripts namely module.js, service.js, Homecontroller.js.

**The question is I want to display  first item from the model class. I don't want to repeat the data, instead I want to display only one data(i.e FirstName).and also In the Next line  I want to display the full name.
I have not written function for fullname.Please reply how to write function for fullname and displaying first data**

// Model class : Doctor.cs

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Reg_No { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
}


Web api controller for Doctor

public class DoctorsAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private DigitalHealthWebContext db = new DigitalHealthWebContext();

        // GET: api/DoctorsAPI
        public List<Doctor> GetDoctors()
        {
            return db.Doctors.ToList();
        }
}
```

I have 3 scripts

```
Module.js
var app = angular.module("docModule", ["ngRoute"]);

Service.js
app.service('docService', function ($http) {

    this.getDoctors = function () {
        return $http.get("/api/DoctorsAPI");
    }
})




homeController.js
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, docService) {
   getFormData();
   function getFormData() {
 var DoctorGet = docService.getDoctors();//The MEthod Call from service
       DoctorGet.then(function (p1) { $scope.LoadDoctor = p1.data },
           function (errorP1) {

               $log.error('failure loading Doctor', errorP1);
           });
   }
});
```

if I use select controller with ng-Repeat I am able to get the data.

```
<select ng-model="Dept" class="dropdown form-control" required id="selectControl">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose speaciality</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="Doctor in LoadDoctor" value="{{Doctor.Id}}">
                                    {{Doctor.firstName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
```

but If I write the following code  I am not getting the data

```
     <div class="doc-details-block" ng-controller="homeController">
                    <a href="#" ng-model="LoadDoctor">
                        <h2 class="doc-name">
                            {{firstName}}
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's problem related to trying get firstName property on array with doctors.

You can try to improve it by follow script, but it will be much better to have dedicated property that store a doctor (and again better to have a dedicated service call, because it's more clear and faster)

```
    <div class="doc-details-block" ng-controller="homeController">
        <a ng-if="LoadDoctor.length > 0" href="#">
            <h2 class="doc-name">
                {{ LoadDpctor[0].firstName }}
            </h2>
        </a>
    </div>
```